# How can I configure Log4j2 to roll log files eagerly?

Tags: java, log4j2

I have some log files which I want to roll over daily and archive into gzips.

The relevant configuration looks like this:

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="MyLog"
                 fileName="${sys:log.dir}/mylog.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:log.dir}/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p | %m | %c{1.} [%t]%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="MyLog"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

So a log directory could look like

```
mylog-2020-01-01.log.gz
mylog-2020-01-02.log.gz
mylog-2020-01-03.log.gz
mylog.log  // todays logs (let's say its the 4th Jan)
```

This works fine except that the log file is not gzipped eagerly at the end of the day, it's zipped lazily whenever the first log statement of the following day is appended.

Due to the nature of what I'm logging (related to client sessions), this might not happen until significantly after midnight. It could be hours, or even days.

It would be convenient to be able to `ls` the files in the log directory for the date I'm interested in. At the moment, I can't do that reliably because there is the possibility that yesterday's logs haven't rolled yet; in that case `mylog.log` is **not** the logs from today, but the logs from yesterday.

Is there a way to configure it so that it will roll the files eagerly, not lazily?

I could add a cronjob to do the clean-up but I'm hesitant because if there **is** logging going on around midnight, I don't want to be messing around with files which log4j is trying to write to. It seems like it would be error-prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`

> The `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` causes a rollover **once the date/time
> pattern no longer applies to the active file**

It seems like a cron-based policy will work for me

> The `CronTriggeringPolicy` triggers rollover based on a cron
> expression. This policy is **controlled by a timer and is asynchronous
> to processing log events** so it is possible that log events from the previous or next
> time period may appear at the beginning or end of the log file

[Appenders reference](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)

To execute at midnight every day:

```
<Policies>
    <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * *"/>
</Policies>
```